# SOLR search with hashtags in solr 4.8.1 version

Tags: twitter, solr

I am working with solr4.8.1 and added the types="twittertypes.txt" and i placed the corresponding file in the same location(in which the schema file is available), But still it is not functioning properly. i have removed my data added again after this change in schema(just to confirm that there is no problem with the indexing of old data) but still i face the same issue. Please help me in this.

my schema update is as follows

```
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" splitOnNumerics="0" preserveOriginal="1" types="twittertypes.txt"/>
```

And the twittertypes.txt file consist the following data

```
$ => DIGIT % => DIGIT . => DIGIT \u0023 => ALPHA \u002C => DIGIT \u200D => ALPHANUM
```

Comment: are the other files like synonyms.txt, stopwords.txt are at same location?

Comment: Yes they are in the same location.

Answer (score 0):

there is spelling mistake with your filename saved and mentioned in the filter.They should be same.

"twittertpes.txt" is saved and mentioned as types="twittertypes.txt" in filter.

'y' is missing.

Comment: Sorry its a mistake when i'm posting in this website. I updated the post now. you can check.